# Does C# pattern matching support multiple types?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

Does C# pattern matching support multiple types? For example can we do something like:

```
if(value is float v || value is double v)
```

This of course doesn't work; can't use variable name twice. Also we can't use two different names like `v1` and `v2` because then how would we refer to correctly matched pattern variable and that would effectively kill the purpose of pattern matching.

### Edit

Just to make things converge, here is what I have ended up with (without pattern matching):

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  if (values != null && values.Length == 3 && (values[0] is float || values[0] is double || values[0] is decimal) && (values[1] is float || values[1] is double || values[1] is decimal) && (values[2] is float || values[2] is double || values[2] is decimal))
    return (float)values[0] * (float)values[1] * (float)values[2];
  else
    throw new ArgumentException("All parameters must be of numeric type.");
}
```

There is some downcasting involved, but for my purpose they do not cause significant loss of information.

In my ideal world, I hoped to write it like this:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  if (values != null && values.Length == 3 && 
     values[0] is [float, double, decimal] v1 &&
     values[1] is [float, double, decimal] v2 &&
     values[2] is [float, double, decimal] v3 &&
  )
    return v1 * v2 * v3;
  else
    throw new ArgumentException("All parameters must be of numeric type.");
}
```

Which doesn't work obviously, but just to share my mind. :)

Comment: Use `if (value is float)` and remove *`v`*. Your question should be like this `if (value is float || value is double)`

Comment: @Muaath: Where is pattern matching in it?

Comment: @dotNET You can do `if (value is float || value is double)` and it will work. But you can't use `if (value is float && value is double)`

Comment: @Muaath The point of dotNet's question has gone over your head, I'm afraid.

Comment: This question doesn’t make sense in C# as C# does not support union types. `v` cannot be types as *both* a float and double. Both unify at object only. Using two if-branches are the only way it currently seems logical, where each introduces a variable of the correct type, given the other type restrictions.

Comment: In short you don't, you cant mash types together like this (for good reason, mainly because its not javascript or one of those funky languages) Imagine if you had `if(value is dog v || value is color v) DoSomething(v)??`

Comment: @dotNET what are you hoping to acheive here?

Comment: The switch syntax won't help here has it does not accpet the same variable name.

Comment: @JonasHøgh: I was just confirming that I haven't missed some clever syntactical sugar they introduced to handle this situation. But reading through the comments it looks like that is not the case and I'll have to switch back to the standard old-style casting.

Comment: @dotNET - don’t need the old style casting; only need to properly separate `v` into two distinctly typed variables. The casting bit is irrelevant, as such separation is _also_ required in casting, even if it might not explicitly show such in a separate variable. (The casting might be cleaner in the given problem: it’s not required.)

Comment: Is this the exact scenario you're wanting to handle, where you have something that is either a float or a double? Or is that just the first two types that came to mind?

Comment: @user2864740: Can u post an example plz? Not sure if I have fully understood your comment.

Comment: @user2864740 what would it do? Look for a base class or interface or make a dynamic type... Id says it's not a limitation at all, and a strategic descission to keep static typing, anything else would be a disaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not; and the original ask is fundamentally flawed in that such a repeated variable name *cannot* work to refer to “either” type of value as C# does *not* support [union types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type). This means that **there is no variable `v` that can be strongly typed as `float|double`**<sup>1</sup>. Having the variable typed as object, is the original issue.

Furthermore, C# *doesn't allow a meaningful use* of `if (x is A a || x is B b)`. This is because *either* `a` is is unassigned *or* `b` is unassigned, making access to either variable inside the conditional a poison-pill case — and a compilation failure. Conversely, using `if (x is A a && x is B b)` is a viable guard as *both* `a` and `b` are guaranteed to be assigned.

As to the approach/algorithm itself, the *exact same number of guards and casts are required to implement the solution* when writing both in the same manner; only the number of distinct variables changes. However, this is hidden by a bug in the original implementation with casts.

The “old style” casting code presented erroneously has `(float)x`, where x is typed as an `object`. This will fail at run-time, for double and decimal values. The only way to correctly cast is using the correct cast, each with the correctly refined guard *per cast*, be it capturing to a variable or otherwise:<sup>2</sup>

```
object x = (double)1;

// InvalidCastException - can’t cast System.Single to System.Double
float f = (float)x;

// ok! cast to double, convert to float
float f2 = (float)(double)x;
```

Switching the original code to use `Convert.ToSingle` would address this issue *while continuing to hide* the effective number of casts inside a function and *being a different algorithm*<sup>3</sup> than guarding each value-type. By changing the algorithm, to first convert each value to a float, it also reduces the total number of combinations of summation between types. An equivalent local method could be written with 3 guards.

<sup>1</sup>Generics do not help here because operators are not polymorphic and there is no useful way to constrain T for this problem (eg. there is no ISummable).

<sup>2</sup>This answer makes no judgement on the *equivalent* forms. The only differences are the number of named variables and the number of evaluations of the expression being cast. When the origin code is properly written using direct casts for each type, as to not result in runtime failures, the number of casts — and thus the number of combinations — are the same as when using guards.

---

<sup>3</sup>Here is one way to structure the problem while illustrating the hiding-in-ToSingle and collapsing-to-float effects. I would probably pull the guards *directly* into the sequence loop, as shown by Jard's answer.

```
float? ToFloat(object x) {
    if (x is float f) return f;
    if (x is double d) return (float)d;
    if (x is decimal m) return (float)m;
    return null;
}
```

Then usage with a fixed number of variables:

```
if (v != null && v.Length >= 3) {
  var v0 = ToFloat(v[0]);
  var v1 = ToFloat(v[1]);
  var v2 = ToFloat(v[2]);

  if (v0.HasValue && v1.HasValue && v2.HasValue)
    return v0.Value + v1.Value + v2.Value;
}

throw ..
```

Or usage across a sequence of Object:

```
float r = 0;
foreach (var o in seq) {
  var v = ToFloat(o);
  if (!v.HasValue)
    throw ..
  r += v.Value;
}
return r;
```

Which will also work over a fixed set-as-a-sequence:

```
foreach (var o in new[] { v[2], v[4], v[6] }) ..
```

Comment: I spent some time thinking about it and it looks like this post better covers the fundamental problem and also presents a cover-all-bases solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.

Your best bet is to write two pattern matching `if` statetements (or an `if`/`else if` combination, depending on your preferred logic flow) and use the two resulting variables of type `float` and `double` respectively as input for the same function, so your code inside the `if` blocks is not duplicated.

Comment: Yep. Looks like that is the only way. Problem is that I have got multiple variables that I need to perform pattern matching on, so a clean if/else would become very long. Like if I have just 3 variables and each of them needs to be checked for float, double and decimal, a clean if/else would be some 27 blocks long. A slightly crude hard-casting would be short. I think I can live with that for now.

Comment: Show more of that driving context - why do you have so many things you don't know the type of?

Comment: @CaiusJard: This is basically a WPF Converter class that can receive 2 or 3 values of float, double or decimal types from the front-end binding. In the converter I'm just making sure that the caller has sent in a numeric value and not null or string or anything else.

Comment: Of course I can do regex or other "hacks" to handle the situation. I was just curious if pattern matching is the correct tool for this situation.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to make sure it *is* a decimal, double or float (single statement, handle errors in block) and then use Conversion to convert it to decimal no matter what it is of the three?

Comment: The branches can probably be unified (eg. not 27). Without actual code, it’s hard to actually provide recommendations.. because the casts _also_ require calling out a specific type (eg. cast to double, float?)

Comment: @dotNET *I'm just making sure that the caller has sent in a numeric value and not null or string or anything else* - so why do you  need the value in a variable `v`? Sounds like you just want `if(x is float || x is double)`

Answer (score 1):

How about tidying up with LINQ:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  if ((values?.Length ?? 0) == 3 && values.All(v => v is double || v is decimal || v is float)
    ...
  else
    throw new ArgumentException("All parameters must be of numeric type.");
}
```

I'd hesitate to recommend casting to float, because if doubles are sent in they might not fit, etc.. (and as pointed out in the comments if you have a decimal boxed as object you can't unbox it and cast it to float at the same time)

You'll probably end up doing a `Convert.ToDecimal` on everything, or having something like:

```
decimal d = 1;
foreach(object o in values)
  if(o is float v)
    d *= v;
  else if(o is double vv)
    d *= vv;
  else if(o is decimal vvv)
    d *= vvv; 
  else
    throw ...
```

:)

Comment: Also can’t cast directly to a float from an object that is not a float.. different topic, although the issue is in the original code. If all the values are a homogenous type, that might be further exploitable.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

The answer was posted before the OP clarified that they want the matched variables to have the **same names**. Leaving the original answer as is:

---

You can do something similar in a `switch` - it might be more useful, as you are likely to need different code depending on the type.

```cs
object test = 25.5f;

switch (test)
{
    case float f: 
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a float: " + f); 
        break;
    case double d: 
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a double: " + d); 
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is promising. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Actually it isn't. Just like the standard `if` we can't introduce the same variable again, which means the the main problem remains the same, i.e. body code will be repeated if I use pattern matching.

Comment: The body would also be repeated with casting.. there are other ways to mitigate body repeat. A `return` can also substitute `break` if getting a bit friendly with local methods.

Comment: I am confused now :D You want variables of different types with the **same name**?

Comment: I'm afraid you need a discriminated union, which is not supported afaik.

Comment: This is the same as `if(x is float f) else if (x is double d)` that the OP declared he didn't want

Comment: @CaiusJard, when I started writing my answer, the question and the comments looked quite different. Now that I know my answer actually answers a different question, I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Edit it so people know that it doesn't answer OP question or delete it :)

Comment: Problem with being the FGITW! :)

Comment: The original request of “the same name” is _fundamentally flawed in C#_. As such, and with the non-starter of a non-union type, and without artificially creating new scopes which would defeat the original intent, the original post seems as useful as reasonable, being an alternative to multiple if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought it might be useful for others to point out new possibilities in C#.

---

Since C# 9.0 it is possible to write `value is float or double`.

Since C# 11.0 interfaces can have static virtual members including overloaded operators. This feature has been used in the new `INumber<T>` interface (in fact this was the main motivation behind this feature) and is implemented by more than 20 numeric types in the BCL.

With `INumber<T>` you can write

```cs
public T Convert<T>(params T[] vector) where T : INumber<T>
    => vector.Length == 3
        ? vector[0] * vector[1] * vector[2]
        : throw new ArgumentException("Length must be 3", nameof(vector));
```

The `params` argument allows you to pass either an array or individual arguments (I am using a C# 12.0 collection expression to create an array):

```cs
double x1 = Convert([1, 2.5, 3]);
double x2 = Convert(1, 2.5, 3);

float y1 = Convert([1, 2.5f, 3]);
float y2 = Convert(1, 2.5f, 3);

decimal z1 = Convert([1, 2.5m, 3]);
decimal z2 = Convert(1, 2.5m, 3);

double m1 = Convert([1.5, 2.5f, 3]); // mixing float and double
double m2 = Convert(1.5, 2.5f, 3); // mixing float and double
```

You can mix `int`, `float` and `double` as well as other types implicitly convertible to one of these types like `byte`, `short`, `uint` or `long` etc.; however, there is no  implicit conversion between `decimal` and the other floating-point types.

---

Another possibility is to use a vector type like `Vector3`. The advantage is that it offers predefined vector operations. The downside is that is based on (and limited to) `float`.

```cs
public float Convert(Vector3 v) => v.X * v.Y * v.Z;
```

usage:

```cs
// Using the Vector3(ReadOnlySpan<float>) constructor
float t = Convert(new([1, 2.5f, 3]));

// Using the Vector3(float, float, float) constructor
float u = Convert(new(1, 2.5f, 3));
```

---

You could also create your own vector type. I am only implementing the addition operator to keep the example simple, but you get the point:

```cs
public record struct Vector<T>(T X, T Y, T Z) : IAdditionOperators<Vector<T>, Vector<T>, Vector<T>>
    where T : INumber<T>
{
    public Vector(T[] v) : this(v[0], v[1], v[2]) { } // Or ReadOnlySpan<T> v

    public static Vector<T> operator +(Vector<T> left, Vector<T> right)
        => new(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y, left.Z + right.Z);

    public T Convert() => X * Y * Z;
}
```

Note that record types automatically implement a bunch of useful things like value equality and deconstruction:

Usage examples:

```cs
Vector<double> v1 = new(1, 2, 3.1416);
var v2 = v1 with { Z = 2.71828 };
var v3 = v1 + v2;
double v4 = v3.Convert();
var (x, y, z) = v3;
```

Using a dedicated type (either predefined or your own) certainly has an advantage over working with an array, as all the operations can be encapsulated.